# Combine sheet 3 from many workbooks into one new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 77 workbooks and need to combine sheet 3 in all of them into one sheet in a new workbook. I have not done this in years.  I would really appreciate Any help. I modified some code from other webpages but it is not working for me.

Comment: Are all of the workbooks you are dealing with in one folder?

Comment: Hello,Yes I have created a folder for the 77 counties I am working with and I have created a MergedCO workbook in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

If all of them are in one folder then this works:

```
Sub CopySheetsOver()
 Dim Path As String, Filename As String
 Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim wsh As Worksheet

 Path = "C:\Users\MaryGM\Desktop\YourFolder\" 'set the path to the desired folder
 Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls") 'get names of all xls files, change to xlsx if desired

 Do While Filename <> "" 'loop over all the xlsx files in that folder
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    If wbk.Worksheets.Count > 2 Then 'check if the third sheet exists
    Set wsh = wbk.Sheets(3)
    wsh.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   'set the name to be combination of original sheet name and its corresponding workbook:
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = wbk.Name & "-" & wsh.Name
    End If
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The path to desired folder is the one I want the sheet in, right? the desired folder will be the one I want to contain everything, right?

Comment: It is giving a runtime error 1004 Application defines or object defined

Comment: @MaryGM what line gets highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I had which you can tailor to your needs

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
    'Code to pull sheets from multiple Excel files in one file directory
    'into master "Consolidation" sheet.

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FolderPath = "[REDACTED]"
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        copyOrRefreshSheet ThisWorkbook, Sheets(3)
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Sub copyOrRefreshSheet(destWb As Workbook, sourceWs As Worksheet)
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     On Error Resume Next
     Set ws = destWb.Worksheets(sourceWs.Name)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If ws Is Nothing Then
         sourceWs.Copy After:=destWb.Worksheets(destWb.Worksheets.Count)
     Else
         ws.Cells.ClearContents
         ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).Value = sourceWs.UsedRange.Value2
     End If
End Sub
```

It may not work *perfectly*, but it should point you on the right path

Comment: What does `next sheet` says in the middle of the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  I have another Macro which copies all of the sheets from all of the workbooks in a specific folder.  I edited this slightly so that it fit OP's specifications, but I forgot to take out that line.  Editing now.

Comment: Yeah, I know: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html and